# Error message : App Script Google Sheet how to solve it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm new using App Script from Google Sheet and I thought asking the community for help with an issue I'm facing could be a great idea.

I'm trying to find URL website company from company name using Google Sheet. I found this guy on Medium explaining how to do that :

https://medium.com/the-red-fish/automate-finding-a-company-url-with-a-company-name-on-google-sheets-for-free-in-3-easy-steps-7ea77280bcdc

But when I tried to save this code :

```
function FETCH(url) {

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

Logger.log(response.getContentText());

var out = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

return out[0][“domain”];

}
```

I have an error message :  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (line : 5, file : Code.gs)

Somebody knows where that come from ? And how I can solve this ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

These `“”` are not supported in JavaScript.

Replace:

`“domain”`

with:

`"domain"`